# c++ compare object

Tags: c++

I want to compare to objects to see if they are the same in C++.

If I do it in C# it would look like this:

```
object result = human.find();
if (result == Human.NotFound) 
{ return ...
```

How would I do this in C++?

[edit]
C++ code:

```
Class HumanFamily : public std::map <ExString, Human> {
public:
   static const Human NoHumanFound;
const Human Find (const ExString& name ) const {
  HumanFamily::const_iterator it = find (name);
  if (it == this->end()) {
     return NoHumanFound;
}
return (it->second);
}
```

Class calling the above method:

```
Object r = HumanFamily.begin()->Find (name);
if (r == HumanFamily.NoHumanFound) {
  return HumanFamily.NoHumanFound;

}

return r;
```

Comment: that snipped of code could be valid C++ syntax (not saying it would do what you want, but without your C++ code, and class definitions, it's impossible to say)

Comment: it says object was not declared in this scope

Comment: So go ahead and post your C++ code so we can help you.

Comment: @dcinadr: GMan is asking what your classes look like, and the context under which you're calling it. There's not enough information in your question to provide a meaningful answer.  Depending on how the classes are written, what you have there in C# could be valid C++ (change Human.NotFound to Human::NotFound and I think we can make it work).

Comment: @dcinadr: That doesn't make sense. You have some code, yes? And you want to know how to compare things, yes? Do you have a container? We have no idea, you have to *tell us*.

Comment: Uh? What is human.find() looking for? What kind of container is Human? What does equality mean for two instances of object? All of these things matter.

Comment: **Don't** inherit from the standard containers. They aren't designed for it and will lead to pain.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ language does not have the concept of *object*, a class that acts as base class for all classes. With that in mind and assuming that you have a Human class, you would need to define the operator == for the class. One way to do that is:

```
class Human {
public:
    bool operator ==(Human const& ) const;
    /* ... */
};
```

and then later:

```
bool are_they_the_same(Human const& human1, Human const& human2)
{
    return human1 == human2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The C# code is actually comparing addresses - are those two references to the same object, rather than whether those two objects have an equal value.

You should not overload operator== in C++ with the same meaning. In C++ it means checking whether two, possibly distinct objects have the same value. E.g `a` and `b` could be different strings both containing "Hello world" and hence `a==b` would be true.

Your particular code

```
Object r = HumanFamily.begin()->Find (name);
if (r == HumanFamily.NoHumanFound) {
  return HumanFamily.NoHumanFound;

}

return r;
```

most likely involves slicing (the static and **dynamic** type of `r` will be `Object`), and could be just replaced with

```
return HumanFamily.begin()->Find (name);
```

Comment: So perhaps he should / could also compare addresses then.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty terrible. You should not inherit from Standard classes (except `iostream`s) because they do not have virtual destructors- especially when it could just be replaced by composition. In addition, the `std::map` already has a `NotFound` value- `std::map<>::end();`. On top of that, your functions serve no purpose, and it looks to me like you're trying to return polymorphically but actually it's not a reference, it's a value.

You need to get a book on the C++ and actually understand it, because this code makes me think that you seriously need the help.

Hell, you just need to get a book about programming in general. That usage function you posted could be just replaced with `return HumanFamily.begin()->Find(name);`.

Comment: Acutally I cannot return that.  The application crashes if nothing is in the queue.  I am trying to work with code I was given... i don't have much flexibility.